# Jackson takes negative values and converts to valid Date

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson

I have set the **SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS** as **FALSE** both while serializing and de-serializing.

I am passing the Date in "2012-04-18T19:50:00" format from JSON. I have no issues while the JSON input contain digits when they are greater than zero. However i face problem while I try to pass the Date in negative (Example - **"2012-01-28T-1:-1:00"**). This converts to **"Jan 27, 2013 10:59:00 PM"**.

How can I explicitly specify Jackson to accept only positive values for the Date? Or is there any workaround to stop taking in the negative values from JSON for the Date object.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `DateFormat` to use for parsing, and then that should limit valid expressions.

Comment: Setting SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS as FALSE itself uses [ISO-8601 format](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling). There is no need to define 'DateFormat' right?

Comment: Yes, but as per problem description, it seems to accept negative values. To prevent that, you could specify stricter `DateFormat` (default impl does not actually use `DateFormat`, has simplified implementation I think).

Comment: You could (and perhaps should) also file a bug report: accepting negative values is not really intentional... more an implementation flaw.

Comment: I tested from the main class with `date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(t);` where `String t = new String("2013-01-28T-1:-1:00");` and it prints proper time.

Comment: Ah. So it may be that SimpleDateFormat is more permissive?

Comment: What i can conclude is the Date object can take in negative values too but prints them in the proper Date. I cannot check for negative values in the JSON and then pass to Jackson. Right?

Comment: Jackson just uses `DateFormat` you give to it, and passes internal Date value; or uses it for parsing. It does not try to check `String` value for sanity checks. But you can replace it with your own implementation which could do validation before passing it to JDK provided one.

Comment: Thanks. Will try implementing it. I would need to do that while serializing, right?

Comment: While deserializing I think, if you want validation.